# Instrinsic spin orbit coupling in tight-binding Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, tight-binding

I'm looking to write down a second quantized Hamiltonian to include the intrinsic spin-orbit coupling term in addition to the hopping spin-orbit coupling Rashba effect.

How would I construct the term in the Hamiltonian that expressed hopping between orbitals instead of lattice sites, say for the $p$ orbitals with $ l = 0,1 $?

If I understand correctly from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164832/), I could take the expression
\begin{equation}i \gamma \int d^{3} r\left[\Psi(\vec{r})\left(\sigma_{y} P_{x}-\sigma_{x} P_{y}\right) \Psi(\vec{r})\right]\end{equation}

but now $P_i$ would be the linear momentum *inside* each lattice site for the orbitals, rather than a momentum moving between lattice sites (where I have no $R$ term because it would just be unit vectors.

With this, and with the orthonormality of orbital wave functions, I'd like to  write the second quantized form as

\begin{equation}\gamma \sum_{(i)} \sum_{L} c_{iL_i}^{\dagger}\left(\sigma_{y} -\sigma_{x} \right) c_{jL_j}\end{equation}

where I have a second sum in terms of new angular momentum states, but I'm not sure how to act $P_i$ on some orbital $\varphi_{nlm}$ if I just care about quantum numbers and not a position / momentum basis of the orbital.

Edit:
I think the better way to write it would be as
\begin{equation}\gamma \sum_{i} \sum_{L} c_{iL_i}^{\dagger}\left(L \cdot \sigma \right) c_{jL_j}\end{equation}

I'm unsure of where to go from there.

Furthermore, I'm not sure how to solve for the dispersion of the tight-binding Hamiltonian with this new additional term.  I naively want to to think that the dispersion in the lattice does not depend on the angular momentum state at each lattice point, but I'm not sure how to formalize any of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.